# In today extension, how could i get data from the main application？

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, ios8-today-widget

In my app's today extension, I want to get some text from the main app. I tried using NSUserDefault and Notification, nothing I could get. I don't want to copy the same lengthy code from the main app, so how could I do? Thanks!

Comment: add target for extension in main files that could be used in extensions

Comment: Enabled App groups? How you are accessing NSUserDefault?

Comment: @AnilVarghese I can't add app group because i'm not enrolled developer program, is threre another way to share data ?

Comment: No other way. This is the only way to share data between App & extension

Comment: if you can get the data from extension ,i mean if it is from a server, you can add the the server controller class to the extension target.

Comment: @AnilVarghese Thanks, It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Apps Groups Under Targets->Capabilities as shown in below screenshot,it should be unique[image]

Now u can store info `NSUserDefaults`,but u have to use different methods for storing info with app groups name.Below i have given an example

```
NSUserDefaults *sharedDefault= [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.DigitalAnniversaries"]

[sharedDefault setValue:@"3" forKey:@"notification"]
```

Comment: I can't add app group because my ID is not enrolled developer program,   is threre another way to share data ?

Answer (score 1):

If you enrolled Apple Developer program, the app group is a good way,or build a new target to share the data.